# Testing React-router component throws navigator is not defined

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, react-router

I am writing a test spec for the component that uses browserHistory. It throws an error 
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

i tried solution from [Mocha-Chai throws "navigator not defined" due to React-router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078882/mocha-chai-throws-navigator-not-defined-due-to-react-router-component) but it is still not working. May be I  am not being able to use the solution in right way.

Here is my spec file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import shallow from 'enzyme';
import { MyComponent } from 'component.jsx';

const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = doc;
global.window = doc.defaultView;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};

describe('<Component />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  before(() => {
    sinon.stub(Component.prototype, 'componentWillMount');
    wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
  });

  context('Component', () => {
    it('should render component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.type()).to.equal('div');
    });
  });

  after(() => {
    Component.prototype.componentWillMount.restore();
  });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is component.jsx file

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import R from 'ramda';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const query = this.props.location.query;
    // looping through the query object of url
    R.mapObjIndexed((value, key) => this.prepareStateData(value, key), query);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // this push the url every time the component is updated
    if (this.props.urlHistory && this.props.urlHistory !== prevProps.urlHistory) {
      browserHistory.push(this.props.urlHistory);
    }
  }

  prepareStateData(value, key) {
    // this changes the state according to the url 
    switch (key) {
      case 'query1': {
          // do something
        break;
      }
      case 'query2': {
          // do something
        break;
      }
      default:
         // do something
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       { /* render part */ }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.object,
  urlHistory: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: Paste the contents of <Component /> please.

Comment: @bipobe i have added component.jsx.

Answer (score 0):

Your test runner doesn't know anything about the environment that your app is supposed to run in, so  `window.navigator`/`window.location` etc are not available.

`browserHistory` that you're using requires browser environment to work correctly and I assume that this is the issue you're facing. Try replacing imported `browserHistory` with `createMemoryHistory` and see if the test passes.

---

Excerpts from the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#creatememoryhistoryoptions) which shows the difference:

*`browserHistory` uses the HTML5 History API when available, and falls back to full refreshes otherwise. browserHistory requires additional configuration on the server side to serve up URLs, but is the generally preferred solution for modern web pages.*

*`createMemoryHistory` creates an in-memory history object that does not interact with the browser URL. This is useful for when you need to customize the history object used for server-side rendering, for automated testing, or for when you do not want to manipulate the browser URL, such as when your application is embedded in an .*

Comment: As described above createMemoryHIstory does not manipulate the browser URL, it would not be feasible for us to change browserHistory to createMemoryHistory in component. As the primary purpose of the component is to reflect every action in URL, so that we can share the current state of the application to any other user through the URL.

Comment: @duwalanise I only asked you to replace it to see if the test passes. `createMemoryHistory` is not recommended for browsers anyway. Did you check it?

Comment: @duwalanise I can't reproduce your issue - could you create a live demo demonstrating this (using jsfiddle for example)?